# Split "Integers" apart from a string like "ABC123"?

Tags: php, regex, integer

With PHP, I wanna **cut out the "Integers Only"** amongst the strings which are combined by "Characters" + "Integers".

The sample Strings will be:
- AB12 ---------> 12
- GJR987 ------> 987
- X28753 -------> 28753
.. like that.

Is it the way of `preg_split` ? I hope it is but i don't surely know the REGEXP for it. I only know following one but it gives strings only back.

`preg_split('/\d+/',$INPUT,-1,PREG_SPLIT_OFFSET_CAPTURE);`

How can i do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this:

```
$pattern = '/(\d+)/';
preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
$matches = $matches[1];
```

and it will work as you can see here: http://ideone.com/Bnbgd

Comment: Wowww! This is it buddy! Thanks so much and thats so great!

Answer (score 1):

There is a `preg_match()` function... The regex you could use is `'/(\d+)/'`

Answer (score 1):

A nice way using regexp:

```php
<?php
$string = 'GJR987A9FD34';
preg_match_all('/(\d+)/', $string, $matches);
$number = implode('',$matches[0]);
echo $number; # => 987934
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work

```
$test="ABC123";
$final="";
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($test); $i++) {

    if(is_numeric($test[$i])){
        $final=$final.$test[$i];

    }

}
echo $final;
```